# SQL get item within timestamp range and next closes item

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table (items)

```
iteminfo, timestamp_start, timestamp_stop
```

I need to select an item based on a timestamp:

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE timestamp_start <= '2016-12-27T03:00:00' 
  AND timestamp_stop >= '2016-12-27T04:00:00'
```

Now I also need to get the next closest item (i.e. with a `timestamp_start` greater than the `timestamp_stop` of the selected item).

Comment: You may want to show some sample data and the expected results, in addition to what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number to do this (get next item).  I've broken it out as a CTE to make it clear, but these could be combined as sub-queries.

```
WITH item_rn AS
(  -- add a row number based on what we care about getting next (timestamp_start)
  SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp_start) as RN
  FROM items 
), list_in_range AS
( -- get our base list
  SELECT *
  FROM item_rn
  WHERE timestamp_start <= '2016-12-27T03:00:00' AND timestamp_stop >= '2016-12-27T04:00:00'
), next_item AS
( -- get the next item
  SELECT *
  FROM item_rn
  WHERE rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM list_in_range) + 1
) -- combine lists for final result.
SELECT *
FROM list_in_range

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM next_item
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the next closest item".  If you want the id of the next item, use `lead()`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*, LEAD(i.item_id) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp_start) as next_item_id
      FROM items i
     ) i
WHERE timestamp_start <= '2016-12-27T03:00:00' AND
      timestamp_stop >= '2016-12-27T04:00:00';
```

As a note:  You can get the entire record by referencing the table:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*, LEAD(i) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp_start) as next_item
      FROM items i
     ) i
WHERE timestamp_start <= '2016-12-27T03:00:00' AND
      timestamp_stop >= '2016-12-27T04:00:00';
```

The use of a table alias to refer to a row is often confusing unless you are quite advanced in Postgres, so I prefer to think in terms of unique ids.

Comment: He means the row not the id.  There is nothing in the question that even suggests an item_id column exists.... it seems you are being lazy on this holiday. :)

Comment: @Hogan . . . I modified the answer and explained why I "invented" it.  Without sample data and desired results, the question is not particularly clear on what needs to be done.

Comment: wow this really works?? LEAD() on a table name?  I've never seen that -- must be progresql only.

Comment: Doesn't this answer have the same problem Chris' does -- there is no way to know that the next item when ordering by `timestamp_start` is also the next item if you are limiting based on `timestamp_stop`.  Finding an example that fails is trivial.

Comment: @Hogan . . . If I understand your comment, the `lead()` is in the subquery, so it is not affected by the `where`.  And yes, the table alias representing an entire row of data is a Postgres-ism.

Comment: Oh duh... of course this works -- it is the same as my row number solution just uses lead instead of row number

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a straightforward solution:

```
SELECT *
        FROM items 
        WHERE timestamp_start <= '2016-12-27T04:00:00' 
          AND timestamp_stop >= '2016-12-27T04:00:00'
UNION
SELECT *
        FROM items 
        WHERE timestamp_start> '2016-12-27T04:00:00'
ORDER BY timestamp_start LIMIT 2
```

Comment: this won't work -- you don't know that the first item greater the timestamp  the next item.   The next item could be <= '2016-12-27T04:00:00' but not have a stop >= '2016-12-27T04:00:00'

Comment: How could it be <= '2016-12-27T04:00:00' ? The WHERE clause ( WHERE start > '2016-12-27T04:00:00') should prevent this.

Comment: they are two different columns -- do you really need example data where this fails??

Comment: Sry, my bad. Start should be timestamp_start. Fixed it.

Comment: that still does not fix the issue.  the 2nd query in the union can include rows from the first query -- if it includes 3 or more you solution will fail and not give the next one.

Comment: I think I actually need sample data. I dont see how the second query can yield rows from the first one since timestamp_start <=  and timestamp_start > are mutually exclusive

Comment: yes but timestamp_start <= and timestamp_**stop** > are not.  Like I said before they are **two** different columns.